# HightChart Flag is not working, Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17

Tags: highcharts

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ahfsv2k8/14/

I need to show flag only first point and last point like this https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-placement

but with my fiddle not working.

I added :

```
{
                    type: 'flags',
                    data: [{
                        x:  1214784000000,
                        text: 'Flag Aaaa',
                        title: 'A'
                    }],
                    onSeries: 'main'
                }
```

for flag but not working. showing me `Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17` error on console.

Comment: The `flags` type is only available under highstock (which needs highstock.js). You are loading highcharts.js.

Comment: yes, I am not using highstock,  how can I show that with highchart ?

Comment: The `flags` series type is only available in highstock (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/flag-series). You could use the annotations module (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module).